# html image (aborted) in IE but working in other browsers

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to load an image into a canvas element on my html page.

```
var loadImage = function(loadImage, callback) {
var img = new Image();
img.setAttribute('crossOrigin,'anonymous');
img.onload  = function() { callback(Raster(img)); }
img.onerror = function() { alert('error'); }
img.src = "http://localhost/myimage.png";
}
```

The code above loads perfectly on chrome, firefox, etc but gives an error when run in IE. if I look at the developer tools it actually says '(Aborted)' and has 0 bytes received.

I'm totally clueless why it would be aborted or errored if the code works on other browsers and the direct URL to the image loads the image (even in IE). Why would it say aborted if there was no cancellation.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the canvas element and/or the Image cannot be loaded because there are compatibility issues. Did you try to use `<img />` (HMTL)?

Comment: Thing is that it doesn't even go to the canvas element (the onload function) it dies when we assign the img.src. hat's why I doubt it's anything canvas related.

Comment: @user281921 Then I am not sure what is going on. You may have to place a bounty on this question for more attention.

Comment: @user281921 There are cases where using onload will disrupt the loading of other things. Try commenting out your onload function, (by making it a comment) and try to load it then. If this doesn't work, re-write your javascript.